# An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration (1)". Model not available for Performance_Testing_JMeter_App

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am installing the JMeter application and want to run my test classes on selenium application.
By doing the below step, i am facing the internal error:

1. Create a new Java application run configuration in Eclipse for Performance_Testing_JMeter_App. Give it the name, “Performance_Testing_JMeter_App” and set the Main class to “performance_testing_app.Main”. Run this configuration to ensure that your web driver exists.

Does anyone have any idea about it?

I am expecting that it should be run successfully because my driver is present in driver directory

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely unclear what did you do and what you're trying to achieve, also "facing internal error" doesn't tell the full story, you're supposed to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we could see what is the cause of your "internal error"

General thoughts on the approach:

1. First of all be aware that [it's not recommended to use Selenium for performance testing](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

   > Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.
2. There is [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) project which provides JMeter integration with Selenium but according to [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) it should not be used for performance testing as well:

   > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So

- if you're going to use JMeter with Selenium for performance testing please stop, you should rather [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) and use [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers
- if you're using Selenium with JMeter for frontend performance testing make sure to have [selenium-java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java) and all its dependencies installed in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and the relevant driver like [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) or [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)  for your browser binary matching your operating system and architecture also present somewhere
- if you're going to run an existing test from Eclipse you can use [StandardJMeterEngine](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/StandardJMeterEngine.html) class like:

  ```
  StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
  //extra initialization steps if needed
  HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("your-test.jmx"));
  //extra configuration steps if needed, i.e. results file specification
  jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
  jmeter.run();
  ```
- if you're creating a JMeter test from scratch you should use either JMeter API directly (an example can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/)) or better take a look as [JMeter Java DSL](https://abstracta.github.io/jmeter-java-dsl/)